# How to pick entries from each column of a matrix such that their sum is equal to an already specified number?

Tags: matlab

An example to clarify my question is that Let's assume a matrix

```
A=[ 0.8147    0.9134;  0.9058    0.6324; 0.1270    0.0975];
```

I want to select entries from each column such that their sum is always equal or approximately equal to a number say `1` for the above matrix. The selected entry from the first and second column would be `0.9058` and `0.0975` respectively, which leads to a summation of `1` (approximately `0.9058+000975=1.0033`) or any other possible combination which result in a summation of `1`. How can I do this?

**Edit:** Here, Matrix A(3x2) is given only as an example. **Actual matrix** is quite large with **many** rows and columns. Any **exhaustive search** is taking too much time for a large matrix.

Comment: We encourage people on StackOverflow to try and attempt the problem themselves. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are there always only 2 columns?

Comment: @Zobeenay What's wrong with the `ndgrid` solution?

Comment: It would also be a really good idea to mention this in the question. So far all of the answers given assume only two columns in `A`.

Comment: That also should be in the question. If an exhaustive search of all the possibilities is taking too much time, suggesting another exhaustive search will probably not help. Is there anything else you can tell us about the data? Is there anything you know about it that might reduce the search space?

Comment: Yeah, 300^12 is a big number. Unless you have a *lot* of duplicates (within your tolerance), calculating all of the combinations is going to take a *long* time. So I guess the next question is, why do you really need **all** of those sums? btw, if you don't ping me like @beaker, I'm not notified that you've responded. I didn't have to do it for you because you're the post author so you always get notified.

Comment: Yes, the enormity of the real task should have been stated at the beginning.  In the case of a 300 by 12 matrix, your only real chance is nested for loops. We are speaking of 300^12 = 5.3144e+29 combinations to check.  That is going to take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact way to do it for two column A.

```
B = nchoosek(1:numel(A),2);
B(B(:,1)>length(A) | B(:,2)<(length(A)+1),:) = [];
S = sum(A(B),2);
P = A(B(S>.98 & S<1.02,:))  % Set your tolerance.  Here: abs(S-1)<0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most eloquent solution, but I think it should get the job done. You might need to play with the digit rounded to and the number of significant figures in 1.0 to get the exact answer you want.

This solution loops through each value in column 1 of A once with each value in column 2 of A, so it is possible a value in column 1 could sum to ~1 more than once and therefore be duplicated.  To find only the first match you could introduce a "break" in the loop if there is an answer already, or make a sub_matrix to find the sum closest to 1 if you only want one possible match included.

```
% Define matrix: 
A = [ 0.8147 0.9134; 0.9058 0.6324; 0.1270 0.0975];

% Loop through column A to sum with each value in column B
% if the value is equal to 1.0, then it will group the pair numbers in 
% Matched_up matrix and the indices of the match from the original 
% matrix in Matched_indices matrix. 

Matched_up = [];
Matched_indices = [];

for indexA = 1:length(A)
    for indexB = 1:length(A)
        if round(A(indexA,1)+A(indexB,2),1) == 1.0
            Matched_up = [Matched_up; A(indexA,1) A(indexB,2)];
            Matched_indices = [Matched_indices; indexA indexB];
        end
    end
end

% Pair up values and check:
Row_sum = sum(Matched_up,2);

% If what you are ultimately after is the row which has a sum closest to 1
% You could look at the abs difference between the row_sum and 1

[Abs_diff, Row_Closest_to_one] = min(abs(1-Row_sum));
```